False-sharing and OpenMP
I have a question about my attempt to use different chunk size in OpenMP to avoid false-sharing.
So I created 2 large vectors, and measured sum operation time with 2 different chunk sizes.

I used default #pragma omp parallel for
Commented option: I used chunk such that each thread should work with it's own cache-line on writting operation. std::hardware_destructive_interference_size in my case is 64 bytes.

#include <omp.h>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include <new>

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    std::size_t n = 10000000 * 64;
    std::vector<int32_t> a(n, 1);
    std::vector<int32_t> b(n, 1);
    std::vector<int32_t> c(n, 0);

    auto start = std::chrono::system_clock::now();

    // #pragma omp parallel for schedule(static, std::hardware_destructive_interference_size / sizeof(int32_t))
#pragma omp parallel for
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < a.size(); ++i)
    {
        c[i] = a[i] + b[i];
    }
    auto end = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
    auto elapsed = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(end - start);
    std::cout << elapsed.count() << std::endl;

    return 0;
}

However I always get that "#pragma omp parallel for" works twice faster than second option. Why does it happen? I actually just break reading cache, trying to optimize writting operation?
I saw the Use of OpenMP chunk to break cache answer, but it actualy doesn't help me.

To avoid false sharing, processing chunks of cache line size is not enough. You need to make sure that those chunks are "mapped" do one cache line only. Therefore, your data would need to be 64-byte aligned. But std::vector itself does not guarantee that. You would need to use some alignment-aware allocator.

If you have p threads, with the static schedule there will be at most p-1 cachelines total that will be accessed by more than one thread. In other words, false sharing is completely irrelevant in your example.

Direct answer: I don't know why you see the performance difference.
Also: false sharing is irrelevant in your code. False sharing is only a problem if there are many repeated access to the same cacheline from different threads.
Indirect answer: modern processors and compilers almost completely do away with false sharing. Let me give an example. Suppose I have an array a with length p where p is the number of threads. And each thread t continually writes in a[t]. That's a textbook example of false sharing, not?
The following code (computing pi by Riemann integration) runs twice, once with threads writing at distance 1, meaning false sharing, and once at distance 8 meaning a cacheline apart:
  long int steps = steps_per_thread*nthreads;
  double inc=2./steps;

  for ( int dilate : {static_cast<int>(1),8} ) {
    double global_area = 0., tstart,tend;
    tstart = omp_get_wtime();
    vector<double> local_area( dilate*nthreads );
    for (int i=0; i<NEXPERIMENT; i++) {
#pragma omp parallel
      {
        int mythread = omp_get_thread_num(),
          my_nsteps=steps/nthreads,
          my_first=mythread*my_nsteps,
          my_last=(mythread+1)*my_nsteps-1;
        for (int s=my_first; s<my_last; s++) {
          double x=-1.+s*inc;
          double a=inc*sqrt(1-x*x);
          local_area[dilate*mythread] += 2*a;
        }
      }
    }
    for (int i=0; i<nthreads; i++)
      global_area += local_area[dilate*i];
    global_area /= NEXPERIMENT;
    tend = omp_get_wtime();
    printf("Computed area %e in %e on %d threads\n",
           global_area,tend-tstart,nthreads);
  }

Output on an Intel skylake:
Computed area 3.141592e+00 in 1.087189e-03 on 1 threads
Computed area 3.141592e+00 in 1.096964e-03 on 1 threads
Execute program false cores 2
Computed area 3.141573e+00 in 1.116037e-03 on 2 threads
Computed area 3.141573e+00 in 1.096964e-03 on 2 threads
Execute program false cores 3
Computed area 3.141567e+00 in 1.132011e-03 on 3 threads
Computed area 3.141567e+00 in 1.098871e-03 on 3 threads
Execute program false cores 4
Computed area 3.141565e+00 in 1.426935e-03 on 4 threads
Computed area 3.141565e+00 in 1.100063e-03 on 4 threads
Execute program false cores 5
Computed area 3.141564e+00 in 1.129150e-03 on 5 threads
Computed area 3.141564e+00 in 1.103163e-03 on 5 threads
Execute program false cores 6
Computed area 3.141563e+00 in 1.462936e-03 on 6 threads
Computed area 3.141563e+00 in 1.102924e-03 on 6 threads
Execute program false cores 7
Computed area 3.141563e+00 in 1.140118e-03 on 7 threads
Computed area 3.141563e+00 in 1.104116e-03 on 7 threads
Execute program false cores 8
Computed area 3.141563e+00 in 1.369953e-03 on 8 threads
Computed area 3.141563e+00 in 1.106024e-03 on 8 threads

See? Either the compiler or the processor keeps the accumulators in temporaries and only resolves at the end because the second variant which "solves" the false sharing problem is barely faster.

Yeah, got it, thank you.

You can add pragma omp atomic update to the last line of the for loop to enforce the write to memory. Then you should see a difference.

@Joachim atomic would indeed force the write to memory. However it also forces a sequentialization. If only it could be named, like critical, so that you could tell the compiler that the atomic statements can be executed simultaneously.

False sharing only occurs on the boundary between two neighbouring threads. So that is not a problem for omp parallel for. Note that if c is not aligned to cache-boundaries, you actually introduce false sharing on every cacheline. That said, I think the problem is prefetching.
Limiting factor
Try running the parallel for version with OMP_NUM_THREADS=p OMP_PLACES=cores and several values of p. On my system
processors, bandwidth (GB/s)
1, 18
2, 21
3, 20
4, 21
5, 20
6, 20

the reason the speedup is bad is because this benchmark is limited by the bandwidth between RAM and CPU, which is shared by all cores.
Prefetch
In order to hide the latency of moving a cacheline from RAM to the CPU, they will already start sending the next cacheline over (called a prefetch). However, if you end up not needing this cacheline, you will have wasted bandwidth. CPUs will typically guess the next cacheline is the one adjacent to it. They will try to recognize patterns such as in your code as well, but in my experience most CPUs are not good at this. Prefetching adjacent cachelines is suboptimal. You can see the performance getting gradually closer when increasing the chunk size.
